# Drupal Image and GalleryFormatter

Tags: media

I am using the `Image` and the `Galleryformatter` module. I am getting these two errors on configure media page:

```
Warning: Division by zero in theme_image_style_preview() (line XXX of /.../modules/image/image.admin.inc).

Warning: array_intersect_key(): Argument #1 is not an array in theme_image_style_preview() (line XXX of /.../modules/image/image.admin.inc).
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a solution. Just run the following on shell:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 files
```

http://drupal.org/node/873838

Comment: you dont make 777 permission on server, its a bad practice regarding security issue, you need to address it properly, imo sites/all/files/styles

Comment: Yes depending on the account assign rights to `www-data` account. But did it work?

Comment: yea it did work

Answer (score 0):

I found @Sohail to be almost right. I did:

`chmod 777 drupal/sites/example.com/files/styles`

and the error went away and my drupal 7 new image-style worked. I did not have a `styles` or even a `files` folder in `druapal/sites/all/files`

Comment: 777 not a good idea in production site

Comment: cayerdis - a good point. I did some research and found this article on serverfault: http://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver. I'll try another way (probably setting group to www-data) and post back.